# Wordpress rsvp/contact form pre-populated

Tags: wordpress, contacts, rsvp.js

I am very new to wordpress and would like to create a rsvp form with a difference.

For the launch of a company we are having multiple events and i would like to track the rsvp for each event.

Here is the scenario:
I send out paper invites for my wedding and the events and ask them to rsvp on the website and give them the web address, and a unique code.

They go to the website and proceed to "login" which they do with their surname and unique code. Once they are logged in, they can rsvp however they can only see the events they are invited too and can only choose up to the number of people i have allocated them on the invitation.

This will all get stored in the database i have with the contacts name and unique reference.

So where to begin? I am currently looking at contact form 7 but cannot get the form to be dynamic to login.

Any direction would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at http://www.gravityforms.com/

It's not free but it is a MUCH more dynamic and robust form plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth looking in the WP Plugin Repository for plugins tagged with events, events management or RSVP, rather than trying to build a solution from CF7?